# Modiying request headers in an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've made an ajax call interceptor to listen for XMLHttpRequests.

I would like to modify the request headers of the XHR. For some reason I can only change them in `XMLHttpRequest.send()`. Is it to early to modify them in `XMLHttpRequest.open()`? It throws the exception that I pasted in the code below.

So, why do I get an error?

```
(function (open) {

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {

        this.setRequestHeader('foo', 'bar'); 
        // InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to 
        // use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);

(function (send) {

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {

        this.setRequestHeader('foo', 'bar'); // OK

        send.apply(this, arguments);
    };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    var rnd = Math.round(Math.random()*3+1),
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () { };
    httpRequest.open('GET', '/echo/json?delay=' + rnd);
    httpRequest.send();

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zrZ3a/2/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What if you swap:

```
this.setRequestHeader('foo', 'bar'); 
open.apply(this, arguments);
```

to get:

```
open.apply(this, arguments);
this.setRequestHeader('foo', 'bar');
```

does it work then?

Comment: Yea, could you please explain why?

Comment: Because you need to open it before you set it.